# Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL... syntax to use near 'AND status = '1'' at line 1

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

How can I troubleshoot this error?

```
SELECT user_id, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS fullname FROM user AND status = '1' in .../database/mysql.php on line 49
```

This is the actual code:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT user_id, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS fullname FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "user " . $except . " AND status = '1'");
```

I have checked the fields and all my users have a first/last name in their profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a where clause - not just starting with AND

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT user_id
, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS fullname 
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "user " . $except . " 
WHERE status = '1'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing **AND** with **WHERE** - I think that will do what you indend